# Data Web Services (Open/Commercial) to provide Address Validation, Weather Information etc

Tags: web-services

I am looking for some Web Services which can be integrated into my ASP.NET site to display useful information on the side bar based upon the location of the logged in User.

Can anyone provide any insight regarding useful Open/Commercial Data Web services which can be integrated to display useful information like

- weather condition
- Location (Longitude/Latitiude)
- local news 
  etc.

Thanks in Advance..

D

Answer (score 0):

The [Fwix API](http://developers.fwix.com/) is good for your location needs and especially for local news. I've heard [SimpleGeo](http://simplegeo.com) is good for location services, but I have not yet used it. There are many good weather APIs available for free, such as the weather underground API, world weather online. [Programmable Web](http://www.programmableweb.com/) is a good resource for discovering APIs and getting ratings on them.